# Como salvar o maior valor do rowCount()?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Quero salvar em uma variável o maior valor já obtido pelo `rowCount()` só que não sei como fazer a lógica.

Consulta atual:

```
$playeronline = $pdoG->prepare("SELECT login FROM u_hero WHERE login = 1");
$playeronline->execute();
$numeroonline = $playeronline->rowCount();
return $numeroonline;
```

Comment: Não deu para entender o que você quer fazer.

Comment: O rowCount conta quantas linhas a consulta tem certo? então quero salvar a maior quantidade já consultada e so atualizar se o rowCount obter uma quantidade maior.

Comment: Em outras palavras, você quer manter registrado o maior número de jogadores online que o site já teve?

Comment: Isso mesmo, quero fazer tipo um recorde de play.

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade isto não é confiável. Você deveria incrementar um contador próprio toda vez que alguém fizer o *login*, e decrementar toda vez que alguém fizer o *logout* (manualmente ou por inatividade). Quando incrementar ele compara com o maior valor histórico e decide se é um novo recorde ou não.

Comment: O login é feito dentro do game eu monitoro isso, então sempre quando carrego a pagina faço a consulta ao banco do jogo e verifico o login se esta em 1, não sei como posso fazer manualmente.

Comment: Note que isto pode ser bem ineficiente se tiver grande volume. Sua pergunta não está lá muito clara, se der uma melhorada nela eu tento melhorar a resposta.